# Como hago accesible desde fuera de mi k8s local a través de traefik

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, traefik2

Estoy cacharreando con kubernetes y me he montado un kluster en mi pc local usando kind.
También le he instalado traefik como ingress controller, y ya he conseguido poder acceder a una api que he desplegado en el kluster y a un grafana a traves de unos ingress (si hacer port forwards ni nada por el estilo).
Pero con mongo no lo consigo. Minetras que la Api y grafana necesitan un `IngressRoute`
mongo necesita un `IngressRouteTCP`

El `IngressRouteTCP` que he defino es este:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRouteTCP
metadata:
  name: mongodb-ingress-tcp
  namespace: mongo_namespace
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
    - match: HostSNI(`mongo.localhost`)
      services:
        - name: mongodb
          port: 27017
```

Pero me sale este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sigo buscando como arreglar ese error, pero es que no se muy bien que esta pasando...

Answer (score 1):

#### Respuesta corta

Añádale y defina a tu gusto el apartado `tls:` que te falta dentro de `spec`

```
[...]
  tls:                          
    secretName: supersecret     
    options:                    
      name: opt                 
      namespace: default        
    certResolver: foo           
    domains:                    
    - main: mongo.localhost
    passthrough: false
```

#### Explicación

Te falta definir la especificación `tls` dentro del `IngressRouteTCP`. El error te dice que ha leído un `HostSNI` pero no encuentra que hacer con ello, pues el trato viene definido en la seccion `TLS` que no encuentra. No solo es definir el `SNI`, hay que definir como operarlo.

Tienes varias opciones para proceder: instalación manual de certificados dentro de `k8s`, o usar un `certificateresolver` como letsencrypt.

Si tienes experiencia con certificados puedes hacerlo directamente con k8s. De lo contrario te recomiendo empezar con la generación manual y hacer pruebas con `docker`, ganarás tiempo. O bien con letsencrypt servidor `stageresolver` ( ya que si haces muchas pruebas te van a banear)

No olvidas siempre de hechar un ojo a la [documentacion oficial](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/providers/kubernetes-crd/#kind-ingressroutetcp) de Traefik.

He revisado ese [articulo](https://allanjohn909.medium.com/kubernetes-ingress-with-traefik-letsencrypt-and-haproxy-a2d07a6f3188) que también te puede venir muy vien, para ganar tiempo con el aprendizaje.

Comment: Muy util, gracias!